# Убрать .php и убрать слэш

Tags: .htaccess, php

Сделать это по отдельности получается, а вместе нет, помогите.
Сайт без cms. Все страницы с расширением .php.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.progress-web.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://progress-web.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://progress-web.ru/ [R=301,L]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<files .htaccess="">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: Приведите пример того, что есть и что вы хотите получить.

Comment: при обращении: site.ru/uslugi.php или site.ru/uslugi.php/ или site.ru/uslugi/ должно перекидывать на site.ru/uslugi

Comment: Когда ссылки формируются без .php, все работает как надо. Теперь другой вопрос: один и тот же контент доступен по разным урлам: с .php и без него, это не считается дублем? Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Всё гениальное просто.